# Can I query additional info an OLAP cube?

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap

I have a fact table (primary key is gvkey) and 3 dimension tables: company info, date, and industry. I was able to process and deploy the cube - however, when I open up the MDX studio and run the query, I can only run queries with variables that are the keys (either primary or foreign).

For example, the company information has gvkey as the primary key, but also the company name, phone number, etc. But MDX only shows gvkey. Is it possible to run queries with other variables that are not keys as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes absolutely. If you have included company name in your dimension then you can use it.